# What should I eat before/after a workout?

Tags: nutrition

I go to gym almost all days. For every workout I use to weight train one muscular zone and run  about 50 minutes (at low rates, about 130/140 bpm). My target is to burn as most fat as I can (I'm male, so my fat is particularly on belly). Sometimes if I haven't time, I prefear running session (always at low rates, and always about 50 minutes) to the weight train. I'm 28 and my body is athletic, and I always do some sports in my life. The question is:

What should I eat before the workout? What should I eat if i'm going to just run? What should I eat if i'm going to make both weight train and running session? How much time before the workout?
Is weight train on empty stomach unuseful or at worse bad for muscles?

Best Regards

Comment: This would be a much better question if it were narrowed down. I see at least four distinct questions, some of which are themselves very, very broad. Eliminate the ones that don't pertain to your specific situation, and ask the one remaining question very specifically.

Comment: Not related to your question, but IMO [HIIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-intensity_interval_training) is better for losing fat while keeping muscle.

Answer (score 2):

To eat or not before working out really is a matter of what you can handle.  Even the timing of how soon before exercise you eat, and what you eat, is a matter of what your body can handle.  Some people do quite well with fasted training.  If they have anything its merely some Branched Chain Amino Acids (BCAAs) to assist with recovery.  Other people need something to eat.

The type of running you are talking about has fairly low energy requirements.  If your goal is to lose fat, eating before hand may be counter to your goals.  The weight training, if done with heavy weights and high intensity, may require something to give you energy throughout.

Listen to your body:

- If you are exhausted before the training session is over, you need something before you train.
- If you feel sick during training, you either need to not have something before hand or change what/how much you eat.

After you work out, you should have a good meal with both protein and carbohydrates.  The protein helps rebuild the muscles that were used during training, and the carbohydrates replenish their energy.  NOTE: the best time to have carbs is *after* training.  If your goal is to lose weight, minimize carbs at other meals.